# Run Javascript only when comming from specific link

Tags: javascript

I have this Javscript fade effect when opening the page, for example `admin.php`.

```
<body>
<script>
    document.body.className = 'fade';
</script>

...html code...

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    document.body.className = '';
  });
</script>
</body>
```

The problem is I can't figure it out how to run this script **only** when comming from `login.php` page.

For clarification, it's an effect when opening page it's white and then in about 1sec the page becomes visible, creating fade effect.

Comment: I think what you need to look into is window.history

Comment: If you're using php then you can set a session flag on `login.php` and then check on `admin.php` if that flag is set, and if it does, unset it and output that specific JS to the document. You can also check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass along a variable in the query string. For example, link to it with `admin.php?coming_from_login=1`.

Then in your PHP file:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['coming_from_login']) && $_GET['coming_from_login'] == '1'): ?>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    document.body.className = '';
  });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer):

```html
<body>
    <script>
        const referrerPage = document.referrer.replace(location.origin, ""); // Remove the origin to leave just the page
        if (referrerPage === "/login.php") {
            document.body.className = 'fade';
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
                document.body.className = '';
            });
        }
    </script>

    ...html code...
</body>
```